# Flexbox reserves space for svg images that have been scaled

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox

I have a site header and I would like to use flexbox for this.
I use `justify-content: space-between;` to evenly divide the free space between the div's but when I add my svg and scale it down to the size of the header bar flexbox reserves the same amount of space as if the svg was displayed at 100%.

I made a example to show what I mean:

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: blue;
}

.child {
  flex: content;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="child">
    <img src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" height="100%" alt="">
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="child">2</a>
  <a href="#" class="child">3</a>
</div>
<br>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="child">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" height="100%" alt="">
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="child">2</a>
  <a href="#" class="child">3</a>
</div>
```

And a JSiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/03r8vzkn/6/

Is there a way I can avoid this or should I make the svg smaller? This feels a bit hacky because I don't want to make every svg the right size; the scalability is one of its biggest advantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the `display: inline-flex` for the `.child` divs, then they will only take the *content's width*, of  course you also need to make your `img`s responsive:

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: blue;
}

.child {
  display: inline-flex; /* only takes the content's width */
  background: red;
}

img {
  display: block; /* removes bottom margin/whitespace */
  max-width: 100%; /* horizontally responsive */
  max-height: 100vh; /* vertically responsive */
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="child">
    <img src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" alt="">
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="child">2</a>
  <a href="#" class="child">3</a>
</div>
<br>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="child">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/400/?random" alt="">
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="child">2</a>
  <a href="#" class="child">3</a>
</div>
<br>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="child">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" alt="">
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="child">2</a>
  <a href="#" class="child">3</a>
</div>
<br>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="child">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/200/?random" alt="">
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="child">2</a>
  <a href="#" class="child">3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems that the way I want to implement it shows different results for Edge, Firefox and Chrome so i will use your method and add div's in the children. Thank you for your time.